# I have 3 figures that I want to place in a row

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have 3 figures that I want to place in a row. I trim the figures as original figures have a lot of whitespace. The two figures gets placed in a row but one figure moves to the next row. Is their a way to modify the code to place all the three figures in same row? The code is as follows.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
    \begin{figure*}[ht!]
        \subfloat[\label{genworkflow}]{%
                \includegraphics[trim=20 40 50 30,clip, height=2.8 in]{./figures/fig1.png}}
    \quad
        \subfloat[\label{pyramidprocess} ]{%
        \includegraphics[trim=10 40 10 30,clip, height=2.8 in]{./figures/fig2.png}}
    \quad
        \subfloat[\label{mt-simtask}]{%
        \includegraphics[trim=30 40 30 30,clip, height=2.8 in]{./figures/fig3.png}}\\
        \caption{\label{workflow}The overall approach. (a) figa; (b) Workflow for figb; (c) Workflow for figc.}
    \end{figure*}
```

Comment: instead of using height= use width=.3\textwidth and replace \quad by \hfill then there will be room for 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To place all three subfigures side by side in a row, each subfigure's width has to be less than `0.333\textwidth`. If you choose `0.3\textwidth` as the width for the subfigures, use `\hspace{\fill}` (or `\hfill`) the spacing directive between the subfigures, to obtain the maximum possible separation (of `0.05\textwidth`) between the subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
   \subfloat[\label{genworkflow}]{%
      \includegraphics[trim=20 40 50 30,clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{./figures/fig1.png}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[\label{pyramidprocess} ]{%
      \includegraphics[trim=10 40 10 30,clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{./figures/fig2.png}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[\label{mt-simtask}]{%
      \includegraphics[trim=30 40 30 30,clip, width=0.3\textwidth]{./figures/fig3.png}}\\
\caption{\label{workflow}The overall approach. (a) figa; (b) Workflow for figb; (c) Workflow for figc.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```